# Add line numbers to HTML

Tags: c#, javascript, html, reformatting

I need some kind of hack to display line numbers with HTML documents that will be displayed at a fixed width, such that

```
<p>blah blah blah blah ... blah</p>
```

could be rendered as

```
1  blah blah blah ...
2  blah blah blah ...
3  blah blah blah ...
```

in an fixed width box. The HTML is embedded inside XML documents, IE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<pages>
  <page>
    <html>
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pageStyle.css"/>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Example heading</h1>
        <p>Example paragraph.</p>
      </body>
    </html>
  </page>
</pages>
```

Since I'm serving the html to another application I could try and transform the HTML segments in memory somehow (the serving application is in C#, fyi), although I don't think there's a simple way of doing that without having to run some kind of layout against it first, due to the possibility of having different fonts. I suspect that I could do it by injecting script into the page when it's served.

How could I get this to work?

Comment: Exactly how much horizontal space a line will take up is entirely dependent on how wide the font is rendered on the user's browser (which, by my experience, can vary by browser), so I'm not entirely sure this could be done (perfectly / correctly) in a server-side language.

Comment: That's why I'm sortof hoping there might be a way of detecting the way it would like to be arranged in embedded script, and then I would simply inject that into the page when it's served.

Comment: I think the only way to guarantee layout is to create a pdf of it server-side and then serve that pdf.

Comment: I'd wager that a complex JavaScript solution is possible, but before someone goes through the effort, I think you'll want to test whether JavaScript can even be used in this environment. Being embedded inside XML documents, it doesn't seem a certainty.

Comment: Seems to work okay if I insert a reference to an external script like
<script src="test.js"/>